# Android file.exists() not working

Tags: android

Hallo,

Here's some code which writes a data class to a file, then checks to see that the file exists. I can see that the file exists on the emulator, but file.exists() and therefore saveStateAvailable() returns false.

```
    private void saveStateFile() {
    /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "saveStateFile: Started");
    mGameData = getGameData();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = openFileOutput(mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            ObjectOutputStream objectoutputstream;
            objectoutputstream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutputstream);
            objectoutputstream.writeObject(mGameData);
            objectoutputstream.close();
            fileoutputstream.close();
            /*DEBUG*/Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "saveStateFile: State saved to "+mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /*DEBUG*/Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "saveStateFile: Error writing data state file, "+mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "saveStateFile: Finished stateFileAvailable="+stateFileAvailable());
}
private boolean stateFileAvailable() {
    File file = new File(mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION);
    /*DEBUG*/Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "stateFileAvailable: Called ("+mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION+" exists = "+file.exists()+")");
    return file.exists();
}
```

Any ideas?

-Frink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`Context#getFileStreamPath(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath(java.lang.String)) where the `String` is the filename of the `File` object you are trying to access. Then you can call `File#exists` on that object. So:

```
File file = getFileStreamPath(mGameData.pilotName + STATE_FILE_EXTENSION);
```

Gives you access to the `File` object that points to the correct place in your private app storage area.

What your code is going atm is accessing the file `/<your file name>` which is on the root path. You file obviously does not exist there.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I thought that apps only had access to their own files